# Problems deploying SSAS project to server

Tags: sql, deployment, ssas, cubes

I'm using Visual Studios 2012 and SQL Server 2014. Here's my problem. If I deploy my SSAS solution to 'localhost' everything runs smoothly. When I try to deploy it one of our other servers I receive these errors. I’ve tried changing the accounts in ‘Impersonation Information’, but still get the same errors. I've also made sure I have all admin rights. It’s going on two days and I still cannot find the fix.
Errors:
[image]

Comment: I forgot to add an image description. Yes, I'm new.

Comment: Is your database hosted on the same server as your app? Can you make sure you can connect to the database from your app server successfully?

Comment: My app (visual studios) is on my local machine. The database engine (where I'm pulling the data) and the Analysis Server (where I want to deploy) are on the same server. When I test the Data Source connection, it is successful.

Answer (score 0):

"Class not registered" error indicates your data source (SQL) connection string is using a driver not installed. For example if your connection string uses a SQL2008 driver accidentally (with a Provider=SQLNCLI10.1 connection string) it will give this error when you try to process on the server.

Three options to fix it:

1. Fix the connection string in Visual Studio to use the version of driver that's on the server before you deploy.
2. Install the version of SQL Server Native Client you use on the server
3. Deploy without processing the cube, RDP to the server and open SSMS and connect to SSAS and fix the connection string then process.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help.

I had to create the SSAS project in BIDS 2008. Also, I had to delete the dimension created when the cube was created. I then created a new dimension using multiple columns as my unique key. Then, attached new dimension to the cube.